# a basic question about complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let
$$
\gamma_1:[a,b]\to\mathbb C,\qquad
\gamma_2:[a,b]\to\mathbb C
$$
be two one-to-one, continuously differentiable parametrizations of the same (oriented) curve $\Gamma$. In addition, suppose that $f(z)$ is a complex function which is continuous on a region containing $\Gamma$.

I know that if there exists a strictly increasing and continuously differentiable function $\alpha:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ such that

$\gamma_2(t)=\gamma_1(\alpha(t))$ for every $t\in[a,b]$, then
$$
(\ast)\qquad \int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz.
$$
**My question**: Can we deduce $(\ast)$ merely by the fact that $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are parametrizations of the same curve? Is the existence of $\alpha$ not guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such $\alpha$ exists, then necessarily, $\alpha = \gamma_1^{-1} \circ \gamma_2$. The question is whether $\alpha$ is $C^1$. Counterexamples show that this is not true under the hypotheses you stated.

To state the result, I will change the domains of $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ to be $(a_1, b_1)$ and $(a_2, b_2)$ respectively. The result is that if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are homeomorphisms onto their images $U_1, U_2 \subset \Gamma$ (which can be different) and are $C^1$ with nonvanishing derivative at each point, then the transition map $\gamma_1^{-1} \circ \gamma_2 : \gamma_2^{-1}(U_1 \cap U_2) \to \gamma_1^{-1}(U_1 \cap U_2)$ is $C^1$ with $C^1$ inverse. See discussion on pages 135-137 here for the proof of the $m$-dimensional version of the above result: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are one to one, continuously differential parametrizations of the same oriented curve $\Gamma$, you can take $\alpha : [a,b] \to [a,b],\; \alpha = \gamma_1^{-1}\circ \gamma_2$.

Comment: Thanks @jjagmath. Does $\gamma_1^{-1}\circ\gamma_2$ will be strictly increasing?

Comment: Some subtleties... If $\gamma_1$ is bijective and continuously differentiable, you can't guarantee $\gamma_1^{-1}$ is differentiable, eg $\gamma_1(t) = t^3$ and $\gamma_2(t) = t$ on $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: @boaz Yes, since it will be a continuous bijection from $[a,b]$ to $[a,b]$, and since we are talking about an **oriented** curve $\Gamma$, both travel in the same direction. The other possibility would be that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ traverse the curve in opposite directions, but then they would be parametrizations of the same curve, but not of the same **oriented** curve.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Oops, you're right. May be this could be fixed, but now I'm not sure my answer is right.

Comment: Thanks @Izaak van Dongen. So if $\gamma_1^{-1}$ is  differentiable, then $(\ast)$ is true?