# Complex integrals and parametrization

Tags: complex-analysis

Let
$$
\gamma_1:[a,b]\to\mathbb C,\qquad
\gamma_2:[a,b]\to\mathbb C
$$
be two one-to-one, continuously differentiable parametrizations of the same (oriented) curve $\Gamma$. In addition, suppose that $f(z)$ is a complex function which is continuous on a region containing $\Gamma$.

I know that if there exists a strictly increasing and continuously differentiable function $\alpha:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ such that

$\gamma_2(t)=\gamma_1(\alpha(t))$ for every $t\in[a,b]$, then
$$
(\ast)\qquad \int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz.
$$

I know now that if $\alpha$ exists, then we must have that $\alpha=\gamma_1^{-1}\circ\gamma_2$. But since we can't guarantee that $\gamma_1^{-1}$ is differentiable, then such $\alpha$ may not exists (see [a basic question about complex integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380586/a-basic-question-about-complex-integrals)).

**My question**: Can we deduce $(\ast)$ merely by the fact that $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are parametrization of the same curve? I don't see how the differentiability of $\alpha$ affects $(\ast)$ to be true. For example, if we take $\gamma_2(t)=t$ and $\gamma_1(t)=t^3$ for $t\in[-1,1]$, then $\alpha=\gamma_1^{-1}\circ \gamma_2$ is not differentiable, but still we have that
$$
\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz
$$
This question bothering me for a long time. I would happy is someone provide a counterexample.